# Connection to instance Ec2 ssh error (spark cluster)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have a spark (1.3.1) cluster on ec2 (region: us-east). Since the past two months I haven't had any problem with it, but since yesterday I can't ssh one slave (or I can but it takes a really really really long time). My jobs don't fail, they are just waiting and waiting because they are trying to connect to one slave and the slave doesn't answer.

I tried to create a new spark with spark-ec2, but I got this error :

```
Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: 54.90.24.42
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: ssh: connect to host 54.90.24.42 port 22: Connection refused

.

Warning: SSH connection error. (This could be temporary.)
Host: XX.XXX.XXX.XX
SSH return code: 255
SSH output: ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XXX.XX port 22: Connection refused
```

As I am writing a colleague report a similar problem on another cluster :

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to ip-10-231-187-233.ec2.internal/10.231.187.233:54801
```

All those problems seem to be linked.

Does someone have an idea what could it be?

Comment: The AWS AZ for your instances is showing healthy? Have you tried rebooting the slave ec2 instance ?

Comment: Yes I tried to reboot several time. Instance reachability check passed and System reachability check passed.

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour when instances run out of memory.  Sometimes I've been able to get in immediately after a reboot, but have had to be quick.  Depending on what your server does, you may be able to prevent excess memory usage by cutting it off from the network using security groups?

Comment: My job is the same job every week and the memory consumption is the same and not really high. When I am trying to create a new cluster I also have "Waiting for all instances in cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state.........SSH return code: 255". So I don't think the problem is link to excess memory.
What do you mean by "cutting it off from the network using security groups?"

Comment: Don't close it's temporary. mine is worked after 600 seconds